# Open a docx file bookmark in OOS(office online server) using Url parameter

Tags: office, oos

I recently install Office Online Server on my SharePoint Site. Then I upload a word document containing bookmarks in my SharePoint documents.

Now I want to open that doc using URL address to go to specific Bookmark.

For example I want to open that document to see bookmark10. I need some url like this : http://localhost/pages/01.docx?bookmark=b10

Have OOS(Office Online Server) something like this parameter?